# What does a phrase "Plunder for all!" mean?

Tags: expressions, pirate-english

A fleet of ships is going to attack other fleet and on the meeting of capitans of the ships from first fleet one capitan tells "Plunder for all!". What does that mean?

**Added** I've looked plunder in the dictionary, but that doesn't seem to make sense, they are not going to take anything from other ships, they are going just to destroy them. I thought it could have been a kind of special phrase, that is common in marine speech and rarely appears in dictionaries (in the book, from which I took this phrase it is quite common)

**Added** Alright, I'll accept that there is no other meaning. 
I finally decided that he meant "It would be good for all of us to destroy these ships".

Comment: Of course they're going to steal everything they can from the attacked ships. That's the point of piracy.

Comment: If a captain, esp. one on a pirate ship, sets out with the promise of "Plunder for all".  And then proceed to sink the ships of the opposing fleet he would be in a great deal of trouble.

Comment: Can you post the paragraph, or more of the text from the source?

Comment: In context, he means they'll each get to steal from the ships they attack (and they'll all get something for the risk). "I hear there's lots of plunderin' down in New Mexico!" - *The Last Saskatchewan Pirate* - [Arrogant Worms](http://artists.letssingit.com/arrogant-worms-lyrics-the-last-saskatchewan-pirate-c73bzxw)

Comment: lmao at the editor who added the "pirate-english" tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only explanation  that seems feasible is, he is telling his men to "go for it". To cause anarchy. The implication could be that they get to plunder the ships and keep the bounty.

If it is a pirate ship, there has to be the promise of a booty somewhere, else why are they fighting?

Comment: Oh, that's a long story for a whole book. But thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

In general, pirates would prefer to **capture** ships, and their valuable cargoes rather than just sink them. They weren't just bored kids looking to cause destruction for fun; they had bills to pay and mouths to feed like anyone else.

Ships in particular were valuable, because they could be used in further pirate attacks, so capturing them was a force multiplier. However, the captured cargo could be quite valuable. It would be distributed amongst the participating crews, so a lucky capture could conceivably make everyone suddenly rich. This is what was meant by "Plunder for all!"

Comment: pirate-english - I didn't add this tag, it did someone else, relax, I didn't ask what would pirates prefer :) I have already decided how to translate this phrase ;^)

Comment: @user1956641 - Umm...OK. But I fail to see how that comment has anything to do with my answer. Did you perhaps mean to attach it to another post? (way confused)